# Create new column based on some conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following table. Let's call it `orders`. I would like to add a new column to this existing table which calculates the days apart from the first order date by the customerid. If there are 0 days apart from the minimum sold date, then it should be 0.

From this

```
customerid orderdate
1          1/21/2018
1          1/21/2018
1          2/21/2018
1          5/22/2018
2          3/22/2018
3          4/5/2018
3          4/5/2018
```

to this

```
customerid orderdate daysapart
1          1/21/2018         0
1          1/21/2018         0
1          2/21/2018        30
1          2/21/2018       123
2          3/22/2018         0
3          4/5/2018          0
3          4/5/2018          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a Windowed Aggregate:

```
select customerid, orderdate,
   orderdate - min(orderdate) over (partition by customerid) as daysapart
from mytab
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    t1.customerid,
    t1.orderdate,
    t1.orderdate - (SELECT MIN(t2.orderdate)
                    FROM your_table t2
                    WHERE t1.customerid = t2.customerid) daysapart
FROM your_table t1;
```

Comment: column/table aliases don't allow space like that way. If you want space then alias must be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed Sorry, that was a typo.